# Why I get a record instead of a table with my function?

Tags: postgresql

I get a record instead of a table when I

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.func_obtener_calle(IN character varying)
  RETURNS TABLE(tip_via_in character varying, nom_via character varying, geom geometry) AS
$BODY$
  BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
      SELECT *
      FROM tramo_vial
```

`WHERE (tramo_vial.nom_via like '%$1%' or tramo_vial.nom_via like upper('&$1%') or tramo_vial.nom_via like initcap('%$1%')); END; $BODY$  LANGUAGE plpgsql`

I allways get a record and I need a table to use after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the columns you require, you will need to specify it in your select statement, be it all of the columns or particular ones

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM public.func_obtener_calle('text');
```

or

```
SELECT tip_via_in, nom_via, geom FROM public.func_obtener_calle('text');
```